# fill the nulls of a column with the mean sum of the division of two columns SAS

Tags: sql, null, sas, proc, proc-sql

I need to fill the nulls of a column with the mean sum of the division of two columns An example would be

```
A B C ... B_01 C_01
5 . .
5 2 3
7 3 1,2
9 3 0,3
4 . .
```

Well, I would like the missing value for column B to be (2/5 + 3/7 + 3/9) / 3 * its corresponding column A
For column new_c (3/5 + 1,2/7 + 0,3/9)/3 * its corresponding column A

I have thought about doing this, but it turns out that I have 60 columns with which to do it and the only way it comes to mi mind is to do this 60 times.

```
Proc sql;
  create table new as
  Select *
  , sum(B/A)/sum(case when B is missimg then . else 1) end as new_B
  , sum(C/A)/sum(case when C is missimg then . else 1) end as new_C_01
  from table_one
  ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Your arithmetic seems off. The answer for the first observation is less than 2.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by 60 columns.  Do you mean you have 60 B columns that all are to be divided by A?  Or do you have 30 pairs of A and B columns?  If the later then why not just transpose so you have 30 observations with one pair of variables and then group be the pair number.

Comment: I have 60 columns, lets call b, c, d.. and only one column A, and the 60 have to be divided by A and, in missign values multiplied the average by A

Answer (score 0):

PROC SQL should be able to do that easily.

First let's convert your data listing into an actual dataset.

```
data have;
  input A B C ;
cards;
5 . .
5 2 3
7 3 1.2
9 3 0.3
4 . .
;
```

Now let's use it to create a new version of B that follows your rules.

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
  select *,coalesce(b,a*mean(b/a)) as new_b
  from have
;
quit;
```

Results:

```
OBS    A    B     C      new_b

 1     5    .     .     1.93651
 2     5    2    3.0    2.00000
 3     7    3    1.2    3.00000
 4     9    3    0.3    3.00000
 5     4    .     .     1.54921
```

Comment: It will be correct if i only have one column B but i have b,c,d,e,f,g...

Comment: Transpose and group by the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Proc MEANS to compute the mean fraction of each of the 60 columns, and apply the imputation rule in a DATA step.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(20230129);
  do row = 1 to 100;
    a = rand('integer', 30);
    array x x1-x60;
    do over x;
      x = ifn(rand('uniform') > 0.30, rand('integer', a-1), .);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

data fractions;
  set have;
  array f x1-x60;
  do over f;
    if not missing(f) then f = f / a;
  end;
  rename x1-x60 = f1-f60;
run;

proc means noprint data=fractions;
  output out=means mean(f1-f60)=mean1-mean60;
  var f1-f60;
run;

data want;
  set have;

  one = 1;
  set means point=one;

  array means mean1-mean60;
  array x x1-x60;

  do over x;
    if missing (x) then means = means * a; else means = x;
  end;

  rename mean1-mean60=new_x1-new_x60;
run;
```

Comment: First of all thanks! Your code is perfect. But when I do f = f/a the new column f dont show the decimals, so most of the column is 0, what can I do to add decimals? thanks

Comment: Did you accidentally attach a format to the variable that does not show decimal places?

Comment: You can remove formats, that might have been applied to your variables, by using a statement such as `format x: new_x:;` in the final step.  The *x* variables were repurposed to *f* variables via the `rename` statement, this causes the *f* variables to maintain the format of the *x* variables, which *might* be something like `4.0`;